# I want to remove '202103' in a list

Tags: list

I have this list :

['20210301', '20210302', '20210303']

and i want to remove '202103' to have this list :

['01', '02', '02'].

I haven't found the right solution. Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: is that Python? Maybe tag the language used to help people with a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your expected result?

```py
lst  = ['20210301', '20210302', '20210303']
to_remove = '202103'
res = []

for i in lst:
    if to_remove in i:
        res.append(i.replace(to_remove, ""))

print(res)
```

Hope so this is useful to you and solves your question.